# How to popup an activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working with chat application. I have developed a grid layout for smileys.
I have two activities A and B.
A is for chat window with smiley button and B for smileys grid layout. Activity B has some to generate a layout of smileys.
I want to popup an activity B when user presses smiley button in A.
How to achieve this??

Comment: Was the answer helpful for you?

Comment: try using fragments instead or you can use dialog box

Answer (score 2):

Edit you manifest file with:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Comment: @Muhannad - glad to help you =) and maybe someone else =)

Answer (score 1):

If i have got your problem then You can create layout with smiley image statically and call in Activity B and use in Activity A.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple activity and for it's design, create a layout that is not full screen layout:

Then add this `Activity` in the manifest file and add this theme to it:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

And then you can add a blur effect to the surrounding of this `Activity` by adding this in `onCreate` of this `Activity`:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```